# Change of Coordinates in PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

How do I solve this pde with change of coordinates?
$$ u_x + u_y+2xe^u = 0 $$ 
$$u(0,y) = ln(1+y^2)$$
I'm confused as to what to do with the $$2xe^u$$ term.

Thank you

Comment: Why do you want to use a change of coordinates?

Comment: The question I'm doing requires the usage of change of coordinates.

Comment: What type of coordinate transform are you looking to make? $(x, y) \mapsto (f_{1}(x,y), f_{2}(x,y))$? Like $u(x,y) = v(x,y-x)$? Or something like $u = \ln v$?

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider the change of variables
\begin{align}
x' =&\ x+y\\
y' =&\ x-y
\end{align}
then we have that
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x'}\frac{\partial x'}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y'}\frac{\partial y'}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x'}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y'}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x'}\frac{\partial x'}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y'}\frac{\partial y'}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x'}-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y'}.
\end{align}
Then the pde becomes
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x'}+\frac{x'+y'}{2}e^u =0.
\end{align}
Hence it follows
\begin{align}
&-\frac{\partial}{\partial x'}e^{-u}=e^{-u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x'} = -\frac{x'+y'}{2} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \frac{\partial}{\partial x'}e^{-u}= \frac{x'+y'}{2}\\
&\Rightarrow\ e^{-u}= \frac{1}{4}(x')^2+ \frac{1}{2}x'y'+f(y') \\ &\Rightarrow \ \ u(x', y') = -\ln\left|\frac{1}{4}(x')^2+ \frac{1}{2}x'y'+f(y')\right|\\
&\Rightarrow u(x, y) = -\ln\left|\frac{1}{4}(x+y)^2+\frac{1}{2}(x^2-y^2) + f(x-y) \right|.
\end{align}
Plugging in the initial conditions yield
\begin{align}
u(0, y) = -\ln\left| -\frac{1}{4}y^2+f(-y) \right|=\ln|1+y^2|
\end{align}
which means 
\begin{align}
f(y) = \frac{1}{1+y^2}+\frac{1}{4}y^2.
\end{align}
Thus, the solution to the above initial value problem is given by
\begin{align}
u(x, y) =&\  -\ln\left|\frac{1}{4}(x+y)^2+\frac{1}{2}(x^2-y^2)+ \frac{1}{4}(x-y)^2+ \frac{1}{1+(x-y)^2} \right|\\
=&\ -\ln\left|x^2+\frac{1}{1+(x-y)^2} \right|.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$$ u_x + u_y+2xe^u = 0 $$ 
The system of characteristic differential equations is :
$$\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{1}=\frac{du}{2xe^u}$$
A first equation of characteristic curve comes from $\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{1}$
$$y-x=c_1$$
A second equation of characteristic curve comes from $\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{du}{2xe^u} \quad\to\quad 2xdx=e^{-u}du$
$$x^2+e^{-u}=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE, on the form of implicite equation, is :
$$\Phi(y-x\:,\:x^2+e^{-u})=0$$
where $\Phi$ is any differentiable function of two variables. Solving it for the second variable leads to the equivalent explicite form : $x^2+e^{-u}=F(y-x)$
$$u(x,y)=-\ln|F(y-x)-x^2|$$
where $F$ is any differentiable function.

The condition $\quad u(0,y)=\ln(1+y^2)=-\ln|F(y-0)-0^2|=-\ln|F(y)|\quad$

determines the function $F(X)=-\frac{1}{1+X^2}$

We use a dummy variable $X$ (or a change of variable) in order to avoid the confusion between $X=y$ if $x=0$ and $X=y-x$ if $(x\neq 0)$. Thus, the particular solution of the PDE according to the boundary condition is :
$$u(x,y)=-\ln\Big|-\frac{1}{1+(y-x)^2}-x^2\Big|$$